# Why am I getting a context error with this simple code?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is my code:

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <View>
        <Text>Hi</Text>
      </View>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "firstapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I followed online tutorials about setting up the correct environment for react native with nodejs and npm but I don't know why using view and text causes "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')" errors. When I a replace the view and text with just a p tag it works fine.